# Problem with viewing single page correctly. (taken half way down the page on click through)

Tags: excerpt, read-more

I have a strange situation occurring with a website that I am currently developing. On the main articles page at http://wptest.lancscps.co.uk/articles/ when the user clicks on the continue reading link to view the single page based on the `single-article.php`, we end up halfway down the page which isn't the desired effect. I would prefer the user to be taken to the top of the page as one would expect.

Has this happened to anyone else and are there any known reasons for this?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `more` tag to split article into teaser and rest of content. "More" link assumes that reader already done with former and tries to navigate browser to that point in full article.

Codex has modifying this behavior documented in [Customizing the Read More > Prevent Page Scroll When Clicking the More Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link) and suggests following code:

```
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
    $link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
```

Comment: Works a treat, much obliged to you!